# How to Auto-Complete a tag with ICsharpCode.TextEditor component?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, text-editor, icsharpcode

I have added the **ICSharpCode.TextEditor.dll** component to my Visual Studio 2017 reference in my C# project. Next, i want to find out a way to Auto-complete a tag. I have provided a GIF image below on what i mean.

[image]

I have provided a code that i tried to debug with the component itself, but it doesn't work.

```
if (textEditorControl1.Text.Contains("<html>"))
        {
            textEditorControl1.ActiveTextAreaControl.SelectionManager.SelectedText("</html>");                
        }
```

The **ICsharpCode.TextEditor** component does not have the same property as a normal **Textbox**.

```
if (textBox2.Text.Contains("<html>"))
        {
            textBox2.SelectedText = "</html>";
        }
```

If i try debugging the **TextBox** version, i get the tag  countless times until i get an unhandled System.StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found exactly what you're looking for [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-autocomplete-html-tags-in-C-Sharp/). The only thing is, that this is a working code for a normal **TextBox**.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoCompleteHTMLTags_CSharp
{
    public partial class Simple_Form : Form
    {
        public Simple_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static String EnteredString = "";
        public static Boolean Is_LessThanKeyPressed = false;
        public static Boolean Is_GreaterThanKeyPressed = false;
        public static Boolean Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = false;
        public Boolean Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
        public Boolean Is_TagClosedKeyPressed = false;

        public String[] tagslist ={
        "html",
        "head",
        "title",
        "body",
        "h1",
        "h2",
        "h3",
        "h4",
        "h5",
        "h6",
        "b",
        "u",
        "i",
        "sub",
        "sup",
        "center",
        "strike",
        "font",
        "p",
        "style",
        "pre",
        "marquee",
        "ul",
        "ol",
        "a",
        "img",
        "table",
        "tr",
        "th",
        "td",
        "frameset",
        "iframe",
        "form",
        "input",
        "button",
        "textarea",
        "select",
        "div",
        "fieldset",
        "span",
        "strong",
        "em",
        "big",
        "small"
        };


        public void ProcessAutoCompleteBrackets(String s)
        {
            int sel = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            switch (s)
            {
                case "(":
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(sel, ")");
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = sel;
                    Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = true;
                    break;

                case "[":
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(sel, "]");
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = sel;
                    Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = true;
                    break;

                case "\"":
                    Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = true;
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(sel, "\"");
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = sel;
                    break;

                case "'":
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(sel, "'");
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = sel;
                    Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = true;
                    break;
            }
        }



        private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            String ch = e.KeyChar.ToString();


            this.ProcessAutoCompleteBrackets(ch);

            if (ch == "<")
            {
                Is_LessThanKeyPressed = true;
                Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
                EnteredString = "";
            }
            else if (ch == ">")
            {
                if (!Is_TagClosedKeyPressed)
                {
                    Is_GreaterThanKeyPressed = true;
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;

                    int oldsel = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

                    for (int i = 0; i < tagslist.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (EnteredString == tagslist[i])
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(oldsel, "</" + tagslist[i] + ">");
                            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart + oldsel;
                            EnteredString = "";
                        }
                    }

                    Is_LessThanKeyPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Is_TagClosedKeyPressed = false;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (Is_LessThanKeyPressed)
                {
                    for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++)
                    {
                        if (a.ToString() == ch)
                        {
                            EnteredString += ch;
                        }
                        else if (a.ToString().ToUpper() == ch)
                        {
                            EnteredString += ch;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int a = 0; a <= 9; a++)
                    {
                        if (a.ToString() == ch)
                        {
                            EnteredString += ch;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            // if user itself closes the tag
            if (Is_LessThanKeyPressed)
            {
                if (ch == "/")
                {
                    Is_TagClosedKeyPressed = true;
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = true;
                    EnteredString = "";
                }
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Space:
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = true;

                    if (Is_GreaterThanKeyPressed)
                    {
                        Is_GreaterThanKeyPressed = false;
                    }
                    Is_LessThanKeyPressed = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < tagslist.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if(EnteredString==tagslist[i])
                        {
                            EnteredString = tagslist[i];
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case Keys.Up:
                    if (Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed == false)
                    {
                        EnteredString = "";
                        Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = false;
                    }
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
                    break;

                case Keys.Down:
                    if (Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed == false)
                    {
                        EnteredString = "";
                        Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = false;
                    }
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
                    break;

                case Keys.Left:
                    if (Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed == false)
                    {
                        EnteredString = "";
                        Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = false;
                    }
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
                    break;

                case Keys.Right:
                    if (Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed == false)
                    {
                        EnteredString = "";
                        Is_AutoCompleteCharacterPressed = false;
                    }
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
                    break;

                case Keys.Enter: EnteredString = "";
                    Is_SpaceBarKeyPressed = false;
                    break;

                case Keys.Back:
                    int sel = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
                    Point pt = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(sel);
                    char ch = richTextBox1.GetCharFromPosition(pt);
                    if (EnteredString.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (ch != '>')
                        {
                            EnteredString = EnteredString.Remove(EnteredString.Length - 1);
                            Is_LessThanKeyPressed = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ch == '<')
                    {
                        EnteredString = "";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```